# JSON ,HTML, MVC5,<execute></execute>

Tags: html, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi all i implemented MVC 5 application this uses SQL Server database, In database i am storing StackTrace of all error , but when i bringing this column data(StackTrace) it is adding  **message**  , Message here is stack trace

Comment: You forgot to attach **stacktrace**?

Comment: at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ElementAt[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Int32 index)
   at AHRI.NextGen.Web.Controllers.ChangeSubscriptionController.Index() in c:\AHRINextGen\NextGenDirectory\AHRI-NextGen\Source\Development\AHRI.NextGen.Web\Controllers\ChangeSubscriptionController.cs:line 22
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)